# Jenkins job to drop old Docker images from Nexus repository

Tags: docker, nexus

My question is about to drop Docker images from Nexus repository

Comment: Any script to automate this process

Answer (score 2):

You could follow a solution similar to "[Cleanup old Docker images from Nexus Repository](http://www.blog.labouardy.com/cleanup-old-docker-images-from-nexus-repository/)".

It uses <del>[`mlabouardy/nexus-cli`](https://github.com/mlabouardy/nexus-cli)</del> [`EugenMayer/nexus-cli`](https://github.com/EugenMayer/nexus-cli), that can be compiled locally on your PC, and then copied over to your Jenkins agent.

From there, your Jenkins job can call:

```
nexus-cli image delete -name IMAGE_NAME -tag TAG
```

Comment: For others coming here after me, respecting that this question and answer have been written last year: While mlabouardy's nexus-cli still exists, it seems dead. Checkout [EugenMayer/nexus-cli](https://github.com/EugenMayer/nexus-cli). It's up2date.

Comment: @Worp Thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.